# docker not start ing exiting ruby

Tags: docker

I am trying build Docker container and start the server. When we use `docker build -t . test` its create container successfully. When we start the container with `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name railsserver test` its start exit status 0 but cant see any process or any open port 3000

`docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS                NAMES
da70e26109b3        foodex              "irb"                    40 seconds ago       Exited (0) 22 seconds ago                        admiring_heyrovsky
73d4a7ca58d0        foodex              "irb"                    About a minute ago   Created                                          jolly_ramanujan
4594ad5ea4ce        foodex              "irb"                    6 minutes ago        Exited (0) 6 minutes ago                         tender_murdock
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential libpq-dev nodejs mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev ssh
RUN mkdir -p /foodex/
WORKDIR /foodex/
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock /
RUN bundle install
#RUN source ~/.bashrc
EXPOSE 3000
RUN bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
ADD . /foodex/
```

Comment: Please provide the Dockerfile

Comment: FROM ruby

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev ssh

RUN mkdir -p /foodex/

WORKDIR /foodex/


ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock /
RUN bundle install 

#RUN source ~/.bashrc

EXPOSE 3000
RUN bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'

ADD . /foodex/

Comment: docker run -p 3000:3000 foodex -d 0.0.0.0 
container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"-d\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"-d\": executable file not found in $PATH".
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Comment: is there any help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Dockerfile to be:

```
FROM ruby
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential libpq-dev nodejs mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev ssh
COPY ./ /foodex/
WORKDIR /foodex/
RUN bundle install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-p", "3000", "-b", "'0.0.0.0'"]
```

and continue to use the same `build` and `run` commands you had above:

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name railsserver test
```

The problem you had, was your `bundle exec rails s` command to run the server, was being executed during the build, by `RUN`. It should be deferred to container execution with `CMD`